# SQL - Having COUNT() doesn't work as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I joined few tables and filtered results using following code.

```
SELECT jmeno, prijmeni, adresa, vozidlo.spz, snimek.timestamp
FROM majitel
INNER JOIN vozidlo ON majitel.id_majitel = vozidlo.id_majitel
INNER JOIN kat_kamera ON kat_kamera.id_kategorie = vozidlo.id_kategorie
INNER JOIN snimek ON kat_kamera.id_kamera = snimek.id_kamera
WHERE TIMESTAMP >= TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

Here is the result.

```
jmeno   prijmeni    adresa  spz         timestamp
John    Doe         Prague  7A2 5109    17/05/2019 08:21
John    Doe         Prague  7A2 5109    17/05/2019 20:50
Vanessa Green       Pilsen  4P8 9370    17/05/2019 06:14
John    Doe         Prague  7A2 5109    17/05/2019 20:50
Vanessa Green       Pilsen  4P8 9370    17/05/2019 12:27
Vanessa Green       Pilsen  4P8 9370    17/05/2019 14:31
John    Doe         Prague  7A2 5109    18/05/2019 15:35
```

This works well so far. The problem is, that I want to limit the results only to these, which appear 3 times or more.

So I modified the query like this.

```
SELECT jmeno, prijmeni, adresa, vozidlo.spz, snimek.timestamp
FROM majitel
INNER JOIN vozidlo ON majitel.id_majitel = vozidlo.id_majitel
INNER JOIN kat_kamera ON kat_kamera.id_kategorie = vozidlo.id_kategorie
INNER JOIN snimek ON kat_kamera.id_kamera = snimek.id_kamera
WHERE TIMESTAMP >= TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)
HAVING COUNT(jmeno) >= 3
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work. As it returns just this.

```
jmeno   prijmeni    adresa  spz         timestamp
John    Doe         Prague  7A2 5109    17/05/2019 08:21
```

But there should be both **John Doe** and also **Vanessa Green** in the final result.

Could you pls help me out to get the desired result?

Comment: your GROUP BY is missing I believe and if you add that, you will need to rewrite the query a bit, as a general rule of thumb each "column" in a select should appear in the GROUP BY clausure too

Comment: `jmeno` and `prijmeni` should have a primary key in their table (always remember to add your schema). Group it by `id` for efficiency. If you don't add a `group by`, all records are treated same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY`.  MySQL allows a `HAVING` clause without a `GROUP BY`.  The entire query is considered an aggregation query and returns exactly one row.

If you only want the repeating parts:

```
SELECT jmeno, prijmeni, adresa, v.spz
FROM majitel m INNER JOIN
     vozidlo v
     ON m.id_majitel = v.id_majitel INNER JOIN
     kat_kamera kk
     ON kk.id_kategorie = v.id_kategorie INNER JOIN
     snimek s
     ON kk.id_kamera = s.id_kamera
WHERE TIMESTAMP >= TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)
GROUP BY jmeno, prijmeni, adresa, v.spz
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

(I encourage you to qualify *all* column names so it is clear what tables they come from.)

The `timestamp` is trickier to include.  Perhaps concatenating them together one the same row would suffice:

```
SELECT jmeno, prijmeni, adresa, v.spz,
       GROUP_CONCAT(timestamp) as timestamps
FROM majitel m INNER JOIN
     vozidlo v
     ON m.id_majitel = v.id_majitel INNER JOIN
     kat_kamera kk
     ON kk.id_kategorie = v.id_kategorie INNER JOIN
     snimek s
     ON kk.id_kamera = s.id_kamera
WHERE TIMESTAMP >= TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)
GROUP BY jmeno, prijmeni, adresa, v.spz
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

If you want the individual rows, then in MySQL 8+, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT jmeno, prijmeni, adresa, v.spz, timestamp,
             COUNT(*) OVER (jmeno, prijmeni, adresa, v.spz) as cnt
      FROM majitel m INNER JOIN
           vozidlo v
           ON m.id_majitel = v.id_majitel INNER JOIN
           kat_kamera kk
           ON kk.id_kategorie = v.id_kategorie INNER JOIN
           snimek s
           ON kk.id_kamera = s.id_kamera
      WHERE TIMESTAMP >= TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)
      GROUP BY jmeno, prijmeni, adresa, v.spz
     ) x
WHERE cnt >= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use  group by  and count(*)

```
  SELECT jmeno, prijmeni, adresa, vozidlo.spz, min(snimek.timestamp)
  FROM majitel
  INNER JOIN vozidlo ON majitel.id_majitel = vozidlo.id_majitel
  INNER JOIN kat_kamera ON kat_kamera.id_kategorie = vozidlo.id_kategorie
  INNER JOIN snimek ON kat_kamera.id_kamera = snimek.id_kamera
  WHERE TIMESTAMP >= TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)
  group by jmeno, prijmeni, adresa, vozidlo.sp
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

and use an aggregation function for reduce the timestamp values (eg: min())

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by employing `ROW_NUMBER` and `EXISTS` if don't want to lost information about each timestamp. Try this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
         jmeno
        ,prijmeni
        ,adresa
        ,vozidlo.spz
        ,snimek.timestamp
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY jmeno ORDER BY jmeno) as number
    FROM majitel
    INNER JOIN vozidlo ON majitel.id_majitel = vozidlo.id_majitel
    INNER JOIN kat_kamera ON kat_kamera.id_kategorie = vozidlo.id_kategorie
    INNER JOIN snimek ON kat_kamera.id_kamera = snimek.id_kamera
    WHERE TIMESTAMP >= TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)
)
SELECT
    *
FROM CTE
WHERE exists (
                SELECT 1
                FROM CTE
                where CTE.jmeno = jmeno
                and CTE.number >= 3
              )
```